# Firebase.Auth.UserMetadata variable a and b in ionic 3

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, ionic3, firebase-authentication, angularfire

In my Ionic3 project, my DB is cloud firestore.  When I cosole log the value for `Firebase.Auth.UserMetadata` using syntax `this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.metadata` (`afAuth` is `AngularFireAuth`), I get variables `creationTime` and `lastSignInTime` which is mentioned in the firestore [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/auth/user-metadata) but there are 2 additional variable `'a'` and `'b'`. Both of these variables contain 13 char numeric value. Can anyone explain what these variables are?